# Eclipse: how to make a class import another class in a different project folder

Tags: eclipse, import

I have a library named `AIMA` loaded into a workspace in eclipse. `AIMA` is split into three different projects: `aima-core`, `aima-gui`, `aima-osm`. Each of these three folders contain an `src` folder with packages (with several classes inside each package). Then I have a fourth project, the folder `Homework 1`, which contains a `default package` with some Java classes inside; these classes must import some classes from the AIMA library packages. The following is a screenshot of the workspace:

[image]

Both `Environment.java` and `Main.java` fail to import classes from the `AIMA` library. I can't make them "see" the packages inside `aima-core`, `aima-gui` and `aima-osm`. I tried by doing `Build path`on the `Homework1` folder, but it didn't work out. It's the first time I use Eclipse (and Java in general). Can anybody please help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the other projects into the class path of the required project. Properties>class path>projects tab>add